# Allow AWS IAM user to launch a maximum number of instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I would like to create a policy to allow a IAM user to launch a maximum number of instances (say, 5). I have found this question, but it doesn't fit exactly my requirements:

[Allow AWS IAM user to launch only one ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210530/allow-aws-iam-user-to-launch-only-one-ec2-instance)

This answer restricts users to only one instance, but not a fixed number.

Seems that IAM doesn't provide off the shelf support for this operation. I have been looking at trying to count the number of instances for this user and use it as a condition for the policy, but I haven't found an obvious way to do it.

Comment: Related https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=174503

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to restrict specific users to a particular number of Amazon EC2 instances. (There are account-based limits, but not user-limits).

I recommend that you **write an application that launches the instance(s) on the user's behalf**, first checking the number of instances already in use. To track who launched the instance, apply a **Tag** with the user's identification. You could then give the user permission to stop/terminate any instance with their specific tag. (Just make sure they don't also have permission to change tags.)

Effectively, the user isn't launching instances -- your script is launching them.

Answer (score 0):

You **can not directly restrict** the IAM user to create a **limited number of resources (EC2 Instances )** by IAM policy. The solution is that you can delete the extra instances if the user goes beyond the limit given. I have faced a smiler problem, and after a lot of R&D I got one solution to do this task by **AWS cloudTrail.**
You can configure a trail using AWS CloudTrail in a specific region or in all region with an S3 bucket to save the trail logs. To read the logs you can use AWS CLI commands like below -

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=Username,AttributeValue=YourIAMuserID --region yourRegionName 2>&1;
```

In result of this CLI command, you will get the log details created at the time of instance launched, you can count the number of instances created by the user from the result array.

You can terminate the instances by below CLI command which is not needed for that user-

```
sudo aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids instanceId --region us-east-1 2>&1
```

There are more possible ways to achieve this task, I am using this one and its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

CloudTrail cannot preserve logs older than 90 days. So using CloudTrail to achieve the logic is not reliable.